# 3rd Party SDKs in Intel XDK

Tags: android, ios, mobile, intel-xdk

As a management requirement our company needs to use Intel XDK AND to use a specific 3rd party Android/iOS SKD within the app.

Is that even possible? If yes, specifically how can I achieve that? What are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends a bit on what you mean by using a third party SDK.  If you mean using their editor to create your HTML/JS/CSS code, then yes, it's no problem.  If you're talking about using Android Studio or something similar to write Java code and XML files required for Android apps, then it doesn't really make sense.

To use another editor, you would simply edit the files with the editor of your choice, then use the XDK to test/debug/build.  The XDK should recognize changes that occur outside the provided editing tools.

The XDK is designed so that basically all the code you provide is HTML/JS/CSS, and the XDK build will generate the platform specific wrapper to run as an app on Android, IOS or Windows, so you don't really do the kind of stuff that an Android or IOS specific SDK would do.

One other thing, you might find some use with other tools to do debugging.  XDK has some debugging and test facilities, but there's no reason you couldn't use other tools as well, possibly including other SDKs, so that might make sense as well.